# Inverting output of /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to inverted the output of /dev/ttyUSB0.
I'm working "C". I'm new to Linux but you won't hurt my feelings if you tell me this a stupid question.

I have 2 sources of RS485; one from a Raspberry Pi that looks like this:

From Raspberry Pi RS485 "shield"/daughter board (/dev/serial0):

```
    +
        |--|     |--| 
        |  |     |  | 
    ____|  |_____|  |_________
    -
```

The other is from an USB to RS485 converter on an Ubuntu machine (/dev/ttyUSB0):

```
    +
    _____  _______  __________
        |  |     |  | 
        |  |     |  | 
        |--|     |--| 
    -
```

**I'd like to invert the 2nd/Ubuntu version so it looks like the Raspberry Pi version.**

Here's my code:

```
int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int baudRateFlag)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)baudRateFlag);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)baudRateFlag);

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); /* ignore modem controls */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;      /* 8-bit characters */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;  /* no parity bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;  /* only need 1 stop bit */
    // TODO: CRTSCTS isn't defined in termios.h
    //  but is in "arm-linux-gnueabihf\bits\termios.h"
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; /* no hardware flowcontrol */

    /* setup for non-canonical mode */
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    /* fetch bytes as they become available */
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to write a separate filter program that does the data inversion you want.  You then pipe the data through that program to the consumer -- both ways, if necessary.  Would that be sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: Swap the + and - wires over?

Comment: RS485 is a differential system. Swap the A & B cables

Comment: OP here. Swapping wires didn't help but thank you. I had the wires swapped before i.e. T => T , R => R. They should be wired T => R , R => T. (T=transmit, R=receive)

Comment: regarding the statements: `cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)baudRateFlag);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)baudRateFlag);`  The contents of the `struct termios` includes the speed indicators.  So, those statements need to be after writing the `tty` data to the I/O,  Also, what is the contents of the `baudrateflag`?  There are several definitions for the different speeds, Which are really bit maps. So you cannot just input `9600`

Comment: there are several constants defined in the header file termios.h, one for each of the available baud rates.  For instance,  `B9600` for 9600 baud

Comment: "baudRateFlag" is set to B9600 on entry to function. I imagine it has nothing to do with whether the output is inverted so I'm curious how why we are talking about speed. Did I miss something?